# How to remove colon from the pie chart - Amcharts?

Tags: pie-chart, amcharts

I just wan to remove the color from the pie chart. Please find the reference in the attachment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the [`labelText`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#labelText) property to customize the label. By default it's set to `"[[title]]: [[percents]]%"`, so changing it to `"[[percents]]%"` will get what you want.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "labelText": "[[percents]]%",
  // ...
});
```

Demo below:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "labelText": "[[percents]]%",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  }, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
  }, {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
  }, {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 99
  }, {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 60
  }, {
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "litres": 50
  } ],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
   "balloon":{
   "fixedPosition":true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but I have searched for this for quite few days and it took me enough time to get the answer. I am answering just to help someone who searches this for their answer.
I resolved this by overriding calls backs of tooltipItem as

```
options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                return `${data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index]}`;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And if you have multiple data sets and you want to have label too, here what I did,

```
callbacks: {
  label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      console.log(tooltipItem, data);
      var datasetLabel = '';
      var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
      return `${label} : ${data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index]}`;
  }
}
```

you can modify it accordingly.
You can this out https://jsfiddle.net/18jmzcx2/

Answer (score 0):

Well fellas, You must include just this line:

```js
pieSeries.labels.template.text = "{value.percent.formatNumber('##.0')}%";
```

Done!